# Xamarin: VS2010 Ultimate add-in or MonoDevelop for Android - intellisense and code color hinting won't work

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

[image]I've been looking and searching similar issues that I found on my testing on Mono but can't find anything.

**PROBLEM:**
My intellisense in visual studio or in Monodevelop doesn't work. How to fix this?

I can still do the work and everything is working fine except for the issues I mentioned.
Can't afford to type everything w/c consumes much of my time and prone of typo error.
Please help.

**NOTE:**

I've downloaded the latest installer found on Xamarin site w/c already has everything in one click (All the prerequisite and requirements are package in one)

**then...** uninstall and reinstall it individually but stil the annoying things persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help with any suggestions about why the install might not be working for you - sorry!

But it looks like Visual Studio is opening this as the normal text rather than XML or AXML.

For the XML editor, including auto-completion on the "android:" attributes, then can you choose "open with" from the file right-click menu in Solution Explorer - within this choose "XML (Text) Editor" - there is also an option to set this as default within that dialog.

For the Xamarin Visual designer - in which you'll see the design surface but you won't see XML intellisense - then you should be able to try "Mono for Android Designer" from that same "Open With".